# How to pass secrets to ansible-test?

Tags: ansible, continuous-integration, github-actions, secret-key

I use `ansible-test` for testing my collection at github (using Actions). For integration tests with external API it needs a secret (token). Normally I use environment variables for secrets in CI, but `ansible-test` clear up them intentionally before running any tests.

I absolutely don't want to use plain `cat $SECRET > secret` for that as it may be archived/published on Galaxy by mistake.

Are there any safe ways to pass secret to integration role?

Answer (score 1):

I just spent some time trying to figure out the same thing.

Basically it's impossible to pass secrets fom GHA to `ansible-test` in a secure way.

Environment variables aren't exposed to `ansible-test`, see: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/testing_running_locally.html#environment-variables

You cannot pass them as an option or argument to `ansible-test` either.

Your best bet (though insecure) is to pass these variables with a `integration_config.yml`: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/testing_integration.html#integration-config-yml

Answer (score 0):

Following the same approach than `rndmh3ro`'s one, I created and `integration_config.yml.tpl` file as following:

```yaml
---
my_var: ${MY_VAR}
my_other_var: ${MY_OTHER_VAR}
```

I populate it with the following bash script `integration_config.sh`

```sh
 #!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")"

truncate -s 0 integration_config.yml
while read -r line;
do
    echo $line
    eval 'echo "'"$line"'" >> integration_config.yml'
done < "integration_config.yml.tpl"
# !! Don't forget the trailing blank line in your template

echo ""
echo "=>"
echo ""
cat integration_config.yml
```

And it works well :)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, GitHub provides secrets for this purpose.
From https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsenv

```
steps:
- name: My first action
env:
  GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
  FIRST_NAME: Mona
  LAST_NAME: Octocat
```

You can also just pass them to whatever command via bash. You can create up to 100 secrets.

Comment: `ansible-test` has no command options to pass anything to tests. There is no command line option, and there is no environment variable options. AFAIK. So, I need help with ansible-test, not with github actions.